# Hide Mailto: link

Tags: php, html, mailto

I have varying mailto: email address on my site which are now being hit with various harvesters and subsequently I'm being spammed.

Can anyone assist me in creating some PHP code for the following:

```
<a href="mailto:info@company.com">info@company.com</a>
```

To prevent the address from being harvested and equally can I use this script on various email address displayed on the site?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution that I've found is to use a bit of javascript. You call a function, passing in the address, and it will print out the link for you. Since most bots don't process javascript, this should work for a majority of cases:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function email(name, domain, withlink) {
        var addr = name + '@' + domain;
        if(withlink) {
            document.write('<a href="mailto:' + addr + '">' + addr + '</a>');
        } else {
            document.write(addr);
        }
    }
</script>
```

And then, when you want to print an email address on the site:

```
<script>email('myuser', 'mydomain');</script>
```

If you want it to make it a clickable link:

```
<script>email('myuser', 'mydomain', true);</script>
```

Note: This is untested, but it should work. There are also more advanced techniques, which some of the other answers touch on, but most of them build off of a base like this.

Comment: Hi, What within the javascript do I edit to add the actual address please? thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The latter two examples are how you add the email address to the page, and you can use whatever email addresses you want: `<script>email('bob', 'domain.com', true);</script>` would generate an email link to bob@domain.com in the exact place that you put that code.

Comment: Great help and much appreciated

Comment: @AlexVidal What should I do, if I also want to add subject along with anchor?

Answer (score 3):

Others have suggested writing the e-mail address using JavaScript's `document.write()`. I don't like this approach because it's easily defeated by bots that bother actually rendering the page. I have received spam on e-mail addresses "protected" this way (not as much and not as quickly as unprotected addresses, but still it comes).

My preferred approach is to write the link using a dummy e-mail address (which can go to a honeypot e-mail address on your mail server, so you can determine which server IP addresses to blacklist). Then use an `onClick` handler on the link to substitute in the real e-mail address when the user clicks it. No e-mail harvester is going to send a click event to every link on a page, it just wouldn't work.

```
<a href="mailto:fake@example.com" 
   onClick="this.href=this.href.replace('fake', 'real')">
Send Us E-mail</a>
```

In this example we start with "fake@example.com" and replace "fake" with "real" when the user clicks the link.

Another idea I like is to have the user enter *their* e-mail address into a form. Then you send them an e-mail using a script. They *reply to* that e-mail address to initiate contact with you. In other words, they don't get your e-mail address until they give you a valid one of their own, and your address is never on the site.

Comment: What if JavaScript is disabled?

Comment: Then the mail will go to the wrong place, obviously, and you might miss as many as *three* e-mail messages from Lynx users. if you are really concerned about that, then the fake link can go to an image of your e-mail address or whatever. Or you could have the fake e-mail address send them an auto-response to which they have to reply for the message to get through. Use your imagination...

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in Javascript. Try something like

```
<script>
document.write('<a href="mailto:inblahfo@company.com">inblahfo@company.com</a>'
.replace(/blah/g, ''));
</script>
```

Comment: that's one of the ways +1 to equal out ;)

Comment: I don't want to repeat myself, but... why that second downvote?

Comment: @thejh I think that's the smart one who thinks that emails can still be harvested even when generated by JS.  Technically true, in practice I think this works, so I fixed your downvote :)

Comment: At first I didn't see the blah in inblahfo and almost downvoted due to regex susceptibility, so +1 for waking me up.

Answer (score 1):

I've always liked the **Hive Enkoder** to create mailto links:

http://hivelogic.com/enkoder/

Comment: Looks good to me. The generated javascript looks completely impenetrable to my eye.

Comment: Seems a bit overkill no?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
function obfuscate_email($email) {
    $obf = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($email); $i++) {
        $obf .= '&#' . ord($email[$i]) . ';';
    }
    return $obf;
}

echo '<a href="mailto:' . obfuscate_email('info@company.com') . '">' . obfuscate_email('info@company.com') . '</a>';
```

HTML source code:

```
<a href="mailto:&#105;&#110;&#102;&#111;&#64;&#99;&#111;&#109;&#112;&#97;&#110;&#121;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;">&#105;&#110;&#102;&#111;&#64;&#99;&#111;&#109;&#112;&#97;&#110;&#121;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;</a>
```

What user sees:

> [info@company.com](http://mailto%3ainfo@company.com)

Comment: The only problem is that the e-mail address is still there in the plaintext of the javascript code. A simple regex will still find it. Fission Mailed.

Comment: Actually I can't see JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to create an image for your company email address :)

Or

You can use this online tool:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var part1 = "me";
  var part2 = "mydomain.com";
  var part3 = "Click Here to Send";
  document.write('<a href="mai' + 'lto:' + part1 + '@' + part2 + '">');
  document.write(part3 + '</a>');
</script>
```

- http://www.hide-email-script.com/

Or

Check out for more methods:

- [Methods to hide email addresses from page source](http://csarven.ca/hiding-email-addresses)

Comment: @Downvoter: Why the down vote? Did you even saw all the possibilities I posted?

Comment: 2nd one should be effective enough. You can even do `document.write(part1 + '@' + part2 + '</a>');` so Bill doesn't have to change his original concept. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the mailto link in JavaScript dynamically like this: http://www.webmarksonline.com/content/dynamicemaillink.htm

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [recaptca](http://recaptcha.net). It makes uses type the words in two images before revealing your email. It's completely secure and it also helps to digitize books. The website provides a great API (copy-paste code) for implementing it on your site

Update - [heres a direct link to mailhide](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use free external services like [aemail.com](https://aemail.com):

> @email is a free e-mail hiding service that hides emails using short
>   URLs redirecting senders to the mailto-url after clicking the link.

After entering an email at aemail.com, you will get a short URL, which can be used to replace your 'mailto' link. Once link is clicked, your user will be redirected to the 'mailto' URL without any notice of the aemail.com. [API](https://aemail.com/developers/) can be used to hide emails/get URLs dynamically.

Example:

`<a href="mailto:info@itee.com">Contact</a>`

Replaced with

`<a href="https://aemail.com/q2">Contact</a>`

Will keep email link working.

Comment: Given the lack of information on/about that particular website, one could be wary of using their services and giving them email addresses that one precisely wants to protect.

Comment: Question is about how to stop the spam, and this is one of the simplest methods I could imagine. I do not not insist on this specific service, or its marketing success, the only reason to mention it, is because I'm using it without any issues/spam. thanks!